# Wait for data to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to add a custom tweet button on my angular app. Here is the code I use to do it:

HTML:

```
<a href="" class="retweet" retweet target="_blank" data-info="{{ data.name }}">
    Tweet
</a>
```

JS:

```
myApp.directive('retweet', function(){
    return function(scope, elm, attrs){
        var API_URL = "http://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json",
            TWEET_URL = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet";

        elm.each(function() {
            var elem = $(this),
                // Use current page URL as default link
                url = encodeURIComponent(elem.attr("data-url") || document.location.href),
                // Use page title as default tweet message
                text = elem.attr("data-info") || document.title,
                via = elem.attr("data-via") || "",
                related = encodeURIComponent(elem.attr("data-related")) || "",
                hashtags = encodeURIComponent(elem.attr("data-hashtags")) || "";

            console.log(elem.attr("data-job"));
            // Set href to tweet page
            elem.attr({
                href: TWEET_URL + "?hashtags=" + hashtags + "&original_referer=" +
                        encodeURIComponent(document.location.href) + "&related=" + related +
                        "&source=tweetbutton&text=" + text + "&url=" + url + "&via=" + via,
                target: "_blank",
                onclick: "return !window.open(this.href, 'Google', 'width=500,height=500')"
            });
        });
    }
})
```

My problem here is that the js fetch the data before the data is even loaded in the page. Therefere the "text" variable is set to {{ data.test }} rather than the actual data which gets loaded later on the page.
How can I make sure the data is loaded on time?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-cloak to prevent rendering uncompiled data:

```
<a href="" class="retweet" retweet target="_blank" data-info="{{ data.name }}" ng-cloak>
    Tweet
</a>
```

You can read more about this here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use `$scope.data.name` directly instead of `elem.attr("data-info")`?

Or you can add the expression as a property:

```
<a href ... data-info="$scope.data.name">
```

And use it like this:

```
scope.$eval(attrs.dataInfo);
```